# Unable to find apache2 directory inside /etc in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, apache2

I am trying to install Apache in Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the steps from [How To Install Linux, Apache, MySQL, PHP (LAMP) stack on Ubuntu 16.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu-16-04).

I ran the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

When trying to run the next command:

```
sudo apache2ctl configtest
```

I get an error as follows:

```
apache2: Could not open configuration file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
```

I checked my `/etc` directory and there is no such directory named as `/apache2`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I recommend you to reinstall apache2. In this way he should create the folder with all the default files.

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Comment: @pa4080, Sure i will, and if you feel that my query was genuine then please vote my question up. Thanks for your concern.

Comment: No harm to run **sudo apt autoremove** and **sudo apt autoclean** after purging but before reinstalling. This makes sure no library versions have changed between installations.

Answer (score 2):

Completely purge Apache with  `apache2-data apache2-utils` and then reinstall it.

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge apache2 apache2-data apache2-utils
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

I solved my problem with this.

[source](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/help-with-an-incomplete-apache-2-installation-on-ubuntu-14-04-x32-droplet)